# How to align Text in Tailwind css

Tags: tailwind-css

[image]

with Tailwind css i am trying to align image and text on both sides, not matter how the text is image and text started position should not change. can you please tell me what i am missing or doing wrong.

**Code:** https://play.tailwindcss.com/kFSxJ8tMdD

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this.

Use `content-start` to pack rows in a container against the start of the cross axis:

```
<div class="h-48 flex flex-wrap content-start ...">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Use `content-center` to pack rows in a container in the center of the cross axis:

```
<div class="h-48 flex flex-wrap content-center ...">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Use `content-end` to pack rows in a container against the end of the cross axis:

```
<div class="h-48 flex flex-wrap content-end ...">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Use `content-between` to distribute rows in a container such that there is an equal amount of space between each line:

```
<div class="h-48 flex flex-wrap content-between ...">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Use `content-around` to distribute rows in a container such that there is an equal amount of space around each line:

```
<div class="h-48 flex flex-wrap content-around ...">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Use `content-evenly` to distribute rows in a container such that there is an equal amount of space around each item, but also accounting for the doubling of space you would normally see between each item when using `content-around`:

```
<div class="h-48 flex flex-wrap content-evenly ...">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```